# Как в событии записать возвращаемую строку в переменную?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Есть функция getMessageText() которая создает AJAX-запрос и функция formatText() которая форматирует ответ запроса в строку и возвращает её как messageText. Вопрос в том, как мне записать в переменную внутри getMessageText значение которое возвращает formatText(), если formatText() это handler события?

```
function getMessageText() {
    let messageXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    messageXHR.open('get', 'http://www.randomtext.me/api/gibberish/p-1/10-45/');
    messageXHR.addEventListener('readystatechange', formatText);
    messageXHR.send();

    function formatText() {
        if (messageXHR.readyState != 4) {
            return;
        }

        if (messageXHR.status === 200) {
            let messageText = JSON.parse(messageXHR.responseText).text_out.slice(3, -5);

            return messageText;
        }
    }
}
```

Попробовал способ предложеный в комментариях. Не работает, так как запрос асинхронный, и сначала getMessageText() возвращает formattedMessage = undefined, а уже потом когда запрос окончен в formattedMessage записывается нужное значение. Использовать синхронный запрос не вариант, так как таких запросов возможно будет много.

```
function getMessageText() {
    let messageXHR = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        formattedMessage;

    messageXHR.open('GET', 'http://www.randomtext.me/api/gibberish/p-1/10-45/');
    messageXHR.addEventListener('readystatechange', formatText);
    messageXHR.send();

    function formatText() {
        if (messageXHR.readyState != 4) {
            return;
        }

        if (messageXHR.status === 200) {
            messageText = JSON.parse(messageXHR.responseText).text_out.slice(3, -5);
            formattedMessage = messageText;
        }
    }

    return formattedMessage;
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что "handler события" не может записывать переменные? Объявляете переменную `let formattedMessage;` в функции `getMessageText` и в `formatText` определяете её значение `formattedMessage = messageText`. В чём проблема?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду записать в переменную которая находится в замыкании, да? Я не хотел сказать что "handler события" не может записывать переменные, а интерисовался можно ли записать возвращаемое из него значение в переменную. Спасибо, попробую сделать так.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что `getMessageText` возвращается до того, как отработает `formatText`.

Comment: @Igor Да, понимаю, я же это описал в вопросе. В этом и состоит проблема что мне нужно вернуть значение из `getMessageText()` после того как отработал `formatText()`